# USB VCP connection fails occasionally

Tags: c, serial-port, createfile, usbserial

My question is quite simple:
I operate 20 CP210x (Silicon Lab) devices over an industrial 20 Port USB Hub.

In one of about 1000 trials to open the port I get a problem: The call to

```
CreateFile(portName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

is blocking and doesn't return. In this case it doesn't help to repeat or to restart my software. Only plugging out/in the device helps.
Of course the port name is including backslashes, as required for higher COM Port numbers. The port is closed without getting an error after each communication by

```
CloseHandle(comport_p);
```

I could give more details on my source, but think, that the relevant parts are the mentioned lines. Is there something else I have to consider in my software or could there be a driver problem?

Comment: It could be a driver issue, or an operating system issue, or a USB hub controller hardware/firmware issue, or a cable quality issue, or an electrical interference issue, or (of course) a USB device firmware/hardware issue. Debugging these things is not easy, and very hard to do remotely. At the very least get in there with a USB protocol analyzer, and make sure you use USB certified cables.

Comment: to me, given the extremely poor amount of documentation, That there is a 'race' condition, perhaps where the peripheral is not yet finished closing a port before the next open of the same port arrives.  Suggest using `sync; sync;` after the 'close' as a method to have the peripheral cleaned up and available before the next 'open' occurs